# How do I take these 2 simple functions, write in differential form, then integrate to get back to the original functions?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

I have 2 functions
$$\mu_1(N,H) = aNH+c$$
$$\mu_2(N,H) = aN+bH+c$$

From my (limited) understanding of differential equations I can then write

$$d\mu=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}dN + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial H}dH$$
and so
$$d\mu_1=aHdN+aNdH$$
$$d\mu_2=adN+bdH$$

I think the above is right but if not then that answers my question.
How do I get the original functions from these differential equations?

I doesn't seem to be as simple as
$$\mu=\int \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}dN+\int \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial H}dH$$
Thanks seems to work for $\mu_2$ but not $\mu_1$

Another wrong approach is to note divide by $dN$ and integrate from there
$$\frac{du}{dN}=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}+\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial H}\frac{dH}{dN}$$
in both cases $dH/dN=0$ so then integrate with respect to $N$ and then
$$\mu=\int \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N} dN$$
which works for $\mu_1$ but not $\mu_2$

It was very many years ago that I *lightly* studied this stuff so an intuitive explanation of the general approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite your differentials as $d\mu_1 = d(aNH)$ and $d\mu_2 = d(aN+bH)$ which integration provides $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ straightforwardly (up to the fact that there is no reason for the constants of integration to be equal).

Comment: @EditPiAf are you saying then that the way I wrote the differentials is wrong? Or perhaps not reversible?

Comment: It is correct but you can write $H dN+ NdH$ as $d(NH)$

Comment: Look in a multivariable calculus book to see how to find a potential function ($f$) for a conservative force field ($\nabla f$) or exact differential ($df$). Or look at MATH 3510 Day 32 in my [YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngQcfmYT4a4&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=89).